# Error when installing Oracle (c21) on Windows 11

Tags: windows, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I had to install this Oracle Database XE Downloads for windows x64 :

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/xe-downloads.html

When I try to install it, I run as administrator and then I get this :
[oracle window result install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpt8i.png)

As the window suggest it I tried to reinstall but keep the same problem.

So I looked in this path and found a log install I think : C:\app\yourusurname\product\21c\dbhomeXE\cfgtoollogs\oui\InstallActions2023-03-14_02-25-06PM
[install logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uXpZ.png)

and I discovered that he tried to had my window profil in a group but he couldn't. So I tried to do it manually and I couldn't too. [error trying to add my profile manually to the group USERS of oracle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDFAj.png)

If someone can help, it would be very nice ! :D

Comment: Off-topic for this site, but... it looks like your user name and PC name are both 'edgar', which seems to cause this problem; are you able to rename the PC?

Comment: And having seen your comment on pmdba's answer, can you check whether the colleague  with the same problem also had matching PC/user names; and the colleague who was OK had different names? (Mostly for curiosity...)

Comment: Thanks for having a look :)
So for the colleague with the same problem he had not a match PC/user, but he has also renamed his PC. For the colleague who was ok he has his initial PC name. Do you suggest renaming our pc with their initial names ?

Comment: No, not really, just so it is not the same as the user name - so anything except 'edgar'. Maybe 'edgarpc'? *8-) Though if that didn't help your colleague then maybe it's something else. I assume you're doing this as an admin user (and same for your colleagues)?

Comment: As I said above, my colleague, for who it doesn't work too, hadn't a match PC/user so... And yes we're doing this as an admin user.

Comment: Are you even using Windows 11 Pro? XE isn't supported on home/personal versions at all, either. Why not use VirtualBox to create a VM with a supported Oracle Linux operating system and install Oracle XE on that? You're currently beating yourself up trying to do something that Oracle has effectively said shouldn't be done, and that the software wasn't designed for, and that it won't support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not appear that Oracle 21c XE is supported on Windows 11, based on [the install guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/xeinw/requirements.html#GUID-5E76BC2B-1FF1-4BB8-8E12-7773BB7949BB) here:

> Oracle Database XE for Windows x64 is supported on the following
> operating system versions:
>
> - Windows 10 x64 - Pro, Pro for Workstations, Enterprise, and Education editions
> - Windows Server 2012 R2 x64 - Standard, Datacenter, Essentials, and Foundation editions
> - Windows Server 2016 x64 - Standard, Datacenter, and Essentials editions
> - Windows Server 2019 x64 - Standard, Datacenter, and Essentials editions

Comment: Thanks for answering. 

You have right windows 11 doesn't appear in the supported version, but today me and some colleagues did the same actions. Among them I know 1 who had the same problem as me and 1 other no worries and this with the same OS, windows 11.

Maybe I can bypass to add my profile in the group 'USERS' manually in an other way ? and then maybe cross finger to get a clean install ?

Comment: The point with it being unsupported is that results aren't guaranteed to be consistent. Even if you manage to get it to install, there's nothing to say that the program will actually work correctly. If you don't have the right Windows OS - say on your laptop - then use VirtualBox to create an Oracle Linux VM with a supported version and install Oracle 12c XE in the VM. Don't try to force it into Windows 11 where you never know what will happen.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will create a VM. I'm just curious if anyone knows why this works for some. Anyway, thanks.